# Beautifulsoup unable to get data from mds-data-table from morningstar

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the dividend information from morningstar.
The following code works for scraping info from finviz but the dividend information is not the same as my broker platform.

```
symbol = 'bxs'
morningstar_url = 'https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnys/' + symbol + '/dividends'
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('GET', morningstar_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, 'lxml')

html = list(soup.children)[1]
[type(item) for item in list(soup.children)]

def display_elements(L, show = 0):
    test = list(L.children)
    if(show):
        for i in range(len(test)):
            print(i)
            print(test[i])
            print()
    return(test) 

test = display_elements(html,1)
```

I have no issue printing out the elements but cannot find the element that houses the information such as "Total Yield %" of 2.8%. How do I get inside the mds-data-table to extract the information?

Comment: Depending on what info you want you extract, might be simpler to try another source like yahoo finance where the quote content is part of the HTML page: e.g., https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BXS?p=BXS&.tsrc=fin-srch or https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BXS/key-statistics?p=BXS

Comment: Hi, this sites works too. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Great question! I've actually worked on this specifically, but years ago. Morningstar will only load the tables *after running a script* to prevent this exact type of scraping behavior. If you view source generally, immediately on load, you won't be able to see any HTML.

What your going to want to do is find the JavaScript code that is loading the elements, and hook up bs4 to use that. You'll have to poke around the files, but somewhere deep in those js files, you'll find a dynamic URL. It'll be hidden, but it'll be in there somewhere. I'll go look at some of my old code and see if i can find something that helps.

So here's an edited sample of what used to work for me:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
exchange = 'NYSE'
ticker = 'V'
if exchange == 'NYSE':
    exchange_code = "XNYS"
elif exchange in ["NasdaqNM", "NASDAQ"]:
    exchange_code = "XNAS"
else:
    logging.info("Unknown Exchange Code for {}".format(stock.symbol))
    return
time_now = int(time.time())
time_delay = int(time.time()+150)
morningstar_raw = urlopen(f'http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4HtmlAjax.html?&t={exchange_code}:{ticker}&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=USD&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&rounding=3&view=raw&r=354589&callback=jsonp{time_now}&_={time_delay}')
print(morningstar_raw)
```

Granted this solution is from a file lasted edited sometime in 2018, and they may have changed up their scripting, but you can find this and much more on my github project [wxStocks](https://github.com/scoofy/wxStocks)

Comment: Does the javascript looks like this? <script type="text/javascript" src="https://mb.moatads.com/yi/v2? remove as it is too long</script> I found this line only after the dividend yield 2.80 element. I couldn't any other javascript before that.